# Saving post id into a session variable after creating a post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am adding an action hook so that after i save a post i will store the information of the post into session variables.

In the beginning of my php file i added: `session_start()`

I then have:

```
function save_post_in_session( $post_ID, $post ) {
    $_SESSION['post_id'] = $post_ID;
    $_SESSION['post_title'] = $post->post_title;
}

add_action( 'created_post', 'save_post_in_session', 10, 2 );
```

I also create another function for the purpose of checking the stored variables in session and checking if post_id is defined then i will go ahead and display a div with a message as follows:

```
function check_new_post_saved() {
    if( isset( $_SESSION['post_id'] ) ) {
    ?>
        <div class='custom-alert' id='comment_custom_alert'>
                <div class='alert-success'>
                    <button type='button' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.remove()' class='close'>&times;</button>
                    <strong>Success!</strong> Your post has been saved successfully.
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php 
    }
}
```

At the end of the file i call the function: `check_new_post_saved();`

After i try creating and saving a post in wordpress - it saves properly but when i check my session storage in my devtools i am not seeing any variables. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Have tried `print_r($_SESSION);`?

Comment: @Jared No - where would i place that call? This is my first time with wordpress so i am wrapping my head how all this works.

Comment: Add this as a first string of your `check_new_post_saved` function.

Comment: @Jared i am not seeing anything displayed on the page. - Array().

Comment: This means your `$_SESSION` is empty. Try the same `print_r` as a last string of your `save_post_in_session`.

Comment: @Jared just tried and nothing printed out .. it seems like the save_post_in_session function is not being executed as i thought. Is the action hook correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if action named `created_post` even exists. Quick googling gives this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post/

Comment: @Jared that did seem to work and now i can see values. But any reason why i am seeing the custom div on page load? Do i need to clear the session after some point?

Comment: If you need to display the alret notice only once, just `unset( $_SESSION['post_id'] );` after the successfull check in your `check_new_post_saved`.

Comment: @Jared Thank you!!! You want to post as an answer so i can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hook that is run after the post was saved is named [`wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post/)